# Bootstrap Dropdown and Bootstrap Tagsinput not working when integrating with angular 2

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, angular

Bootstrap dropdown code works fine (without angular 2) but same code is integrated with angular 2, it fails to work as expected.

**HTML and CSS Code:** [Dropdown is working.]

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
         <li class="dropdown">
               <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                     <i class="ti-user"></i>
                     <p>You can</p>
                     <b class="caret"></b>
               </a>
               <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                 <li><a href="login.html">Login</a></li>
                 <li><a href="signup.html">Signup</a></li>
               </ul>
         </li>
      </ul>
 </div>
```

---

**HTML and CSS with Angular 2** [Dropdown is not working.]

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
         <li class="dropdown">
               <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                     <i class="ti-user"></i>
                     <p>You can</p>
                     <b class="caret"></b>
               </a>
               <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                 <li><a [routerLink]="['/login']">Login</a></li>
                 <li><a [routerLink]="['/signup']">Signup</a></li>
               </ul>
         </li>
     </ul>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
                 <li><a routerLink='login'>Login</a></li>
                 <li><a routerLink='signup'>Signup</a></li>
               </ul>
```

Try this.. with final version, routerLink shouldn't be used as biniding unless you have path params.

Then in router file

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
{path:"login", component : },
{path: "signup", component: }
])
```

Answer (score 1):

Certain Bootstrap Elements do not work in Angular2/4. Luckily the Angular UI team has built out Bootstrap 4 Elements in Angular components.

[Follow these instructions to install](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started)

[Documentation for dropdown](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/dropdown)

Note: this is tested with angular 4.0.3 so you may have to find the version that works with angular 2.